# Dice rolled and coin tossed the number of times the dice shows

Tags: probability

A dice is rolled and the number of dots facing up is observed, then a coin is tossed the number of times that the die shows, you observe the total number of heads. Determine the sample space of this experiment.

I am confused here, since we are only observing and tracking the total number of heads wouldn't the sample space just be the following:

When a 1 is rolled: S = {H}

When a 2 is rolled: S = {H, HH}

When a 3 is rolled: S = {H, HH, HHH}

When a 4 is rolled: S = {H, HH, HHH, HHHH}

When a 5 is rolled: S = {H, HH, HHH, HHHH, HHHHH}

When a 6 is rolled: S = {H, HH, HHH, HHHH, HHHHH, HHHHHH}

since sample space is a set it cannot contain duplicate values thus our sample space is:

S = {H, HH, HHH, HHHH, HHHHH, HHHHHH} as we are only concerned with tracking the number of heads in a sequence of flips.

Is this the right approach or would I need to say something like this:

S = {(i , j) | 1 < i < 6 & j = all combinations of (H or T) from 1 to i times}

for instance

for 1: {H,T}

for 2: {HH,TT,HT,TH}

for 3 : {HHH,HHT,HTT,TTT,TTH,THH,HTH,THT}

for 4: {(H,H,H,H), (T,H,H,H), (H,T,H,H), (H,H,T,H), (H,H,H,T), (T,T,H,H), (T,H,T,H), (T,H,H,T), (H,T,T,H), (H,T,H,T), (H,H,T,T), (T,T,T,H), (T,T,H,T), (T,H,T,T), (H,T,T,T), (T,T,T,T)}

and so on to 6.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample space should incorporate both the die roll and the outcome of the coin tosses.  For instance, you could have an element such as $(1, 0)$, meaning that the die displayed a $1$ and the coin displayed a tail or $(1, T)$ to represent the same outcome.  You might find it easier to identify the probabilities of the events in the sample space if you consider sequences of coin tosses such as $(2, HT)$.

Comment: Your posting assumes (for example) that if the die rolls a $(6)$ and you flip the coin $(6)$ times, and you happen to get $(4)$ out of $(6)$ Heads, that it is irrelevant which order the $(4)$ out of $(6)$ Heads occurs in.  This assumption does seem to be supported by your presentation of the problem.  However, you may have to check whether this actually represents the problem composer's intent.